# Не найден драйвер doctrine, как исправить?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, symfony, doctrine

Убил весь день, перерыл пол гугла.

Есть 2 бд, одна на удаленке, другая локальная, обе mysql.
Локальная open_server.
Когда я на symfony 4 пытаюсь выполнить команду: php bin/console doctrine:database:create, получаю следующее - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) phpinfo -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) сервер работает.
3) phpmyadmin работает.
4) указывал все возможные подборки данных -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нервов уже 0, спасите! Что делать, как исправить?

Answer (score -1):

Все это время я редактировал файл php.ini в OpenServer, а у меня был установлен еще отдельно php7, нужно было редактировать его.